# Scala Tail Recursion java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

I am iteratively querying a mysql table called txqueue that is growing continuously.

Each successive query only considers rows that were inserted into the txqueue table after the query executed in the previous iteration.

To achieve this, each successive query selects rows from the table where the primary key (seqno field in my example below) exceeds the maximum seqno observed in the previous query.

Any newly inserted rows identified in this way are written into a csv file.

The intention is for this process to run indefinitely.

The tail recursive function below works OK, but after a while it runs into a java.lang.StackOverflowError. The results of each iterative query contains two to three rows and results are returned every second or so.

Any ideas on how to avoid the java.lang.StackOverflowError?

Is this actually something that can/should be achieved with streaming?

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Here's the code that works for a while:

```
object TXQImport {

  val driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  val url = "jdbc:mysql://mysqlserveraddress/mysqldb"
  val username = "username"
  val password = "password"
  var connection:Connection = null

  def txImportLoop(startID : BigDecimal) : Unit = {

      try {

        Class.forName(driver)
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)
        val statement = connection.createStatement()
        val newMaxID = statement.executeQuery("SELECT max(seqno) as maxid from txqueue")

        val maxid = new Iterator[BigDecimal] {
          def hasNext = newMaxID.next()
          def next() = newMaxID.getBigDecimal(1)
        }.toStream.max

        val selectStatement = statement.executeQuery("SELECT seqno,someotherfield " +
          " from txqueue where seqno >= " + startID + " and seqno < " + maxid)

        if(startID != maxid) {

          val ts = System.currentTimeMillis
          val file = new java.io.File("F:\\txqueue " + ts + ".txt")
          val bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))

          // Iterate Over ResultSet
          while (selectStatement.next()) {

            bw.write(selectStatement.getString(1) + "," + selectStatement.getString(2))
            bw.newLine()

          }

          bw.close()

        }

        connection.close()
        txImportLoop(maxid)

      }

      catch {
        case e => e.printStackTrace
      }  

  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    txImportLoop(0)

  }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function is not tail-recursive (because of the `catch` in the end). 
That's why you end up with stack overflow.

You should always annotate the functions you intend to be tail-recursive with `@scala.annotation.tailrec` - it will fail compilation in case tail recursion is impossible, so that you won't be surprised by it at run time.